# Why does Qcircuit not load in PDF mode an activate all features?

Tags: xetex, qcircuit

Using the `Qcircuit` package under `xelatex`, I observed this error:

Package Qcircuit Warning: qcircuit is not loading in PDF mode. Activating all Xy-pic features to compensate. If you wish to use specific drivers for Xy-pic, you must modify the code in qcircuit.sty.

A bit of search revealed that it was from the `\ifpdf` statement `https://github.com/CQuIC/qcircuit/blob/2d14e13c13bf9e015aa8f57c47baa67e22900b57/qcircuit.sty#L44`:

```
\usepackage{ifpdf}
\ifpdf
\else
\PackageWarningNoLine{Qcircuit}{qcircuit is not loading in PDF mode. Activating all Xy-pic features to compensate. If you wish to use specific drivers for Xy-pic, you must modify the code in qcircuit.sty}
%    The following option loads all the features in Xy-pic. This
%    this is included as work-around to ensure documents compile
%    images correctly when using XeLaTeX.
\xyoption{all}
\fi
```

This seems rather odd. Is there a way to suppress the error, or should I just move from xelatex or laulatex or something?

Comment: Apparently `qcircuit` doesn't work with `xetex`, so try `lualatex` or `pdflatex`. If for some reason you are bound to `xelatex` then you probably cannot use all features of `qcircuit`.

Comment: But it *does* work with xelatex. It just generates a warning. But if I take it out, the `qcircuit` commands I have fail.

Comment: What you see is a warning, not an error, so if everything works for you, then don't worry. Apparently there are some limitations when using the package with xelatex, where the package uses more of `xy` than it would with `pdflatex`. The warning doesn't stop you from using the package.

Comment: got it. Thanks.